# PupeteerSharp - How to determine element type

Tags: puppeteer-sharp

I am pulling a list of input elements from a page and would like to determine the "type" of each one.

For instance:

```
    var elements = await page.QuerySelectorAllAsync("input");
    if (elements != null)
    {
        foreach (var element in elements)
        {
            if (element.GetType().ToString() == "password")
            {
                await element.TypeAsync("password");
            }
        }
    }
```

However, GetType is not correct.  Is there a way to determine the input type from an element?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to check that on the Chromium's side:

```cs
var elements = await page.QuerySelectorAllAsync("input");
if (elements != null)
{
    foreach (var element in elements)
    {
        if ((await page.EvaluateFunctionAsync<string>("e => e.type", element)) == "password")
        {
            await element.TypeAsync("password");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This causes an exception on the "TypeAsync" line:  PuppeteerException: JSHandle is disposed!

Answer (score 0):

Found that this works:

```
                    var type = await currentElement.GetPropertyAsync("type");
                    if (type.ToString() == "JSHandle:password")
                    {
                        await currentElement.TypeAsync("password");
...
```